# Grails command line redirection in windows

Tags: windows, grails, command-line, stdin

I've been trying to get a co-worker's linux build scripts for set of large grails apps to work in windows (via cygwin). He uses a lot of 'here documents' but I can reduce my problem down to a simple question - how, in windows or cygwin, do I get grails to accept a series of commands from stdin -- i.e. 'grails < cmds'. Every time I try this grails simply opens with the 'grails>' interactive prompt.

I have tried all variations of -Djline=jline.(Windows Linux Unsupported)Terminal  with -non-interactive and cygwin and cmd  (Windows 7 64 bit, grails 2.3.5 by the way) but in all it seems to ignore the redirection of stdin. I've even tried the variation  'cat cmds | grails ..... '

I've looked through the jiras but haven't found anything definitive.  There were some comments about moving to different windows consoles (e.g. conemu) but that didn't solve anything for me.

Moving off windows is not an option :(

Anyone seen/solved this problem before or have any insights ?

Answer (score 0):

What is `grails`? I mean, what **exactly** is started when you run it?

Look in Task Manager or Process Explorer for command line. Supposing, it runs java.exe, so you need to replicate full command line and just use trailing redirector of yours `< cmds`.

Comment: A web dev framework (and a nice one):  grails.org. Yes it is a Java program. It seems the problem is related to jline (which Grails uses to process its CLI, as do Scala, jython and a bunch of other things) and jline apparently has windows redirection issues. I was hoping perhaps someone had already come across the problem specifically using grails - and solved it :)